# Algebra trick clarification question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the equation $x = \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{2} \,\,$ and the trick is that $\frac{1}{x} = \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2}$. I don't see how the minus sign appears just by taking 1 over x?

Comment: rationalise the denominator, or observe that $(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})=1$

Comment: This follows from the general fact that $(a + b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2$. Then it is always the case that if $x = \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}$, $$1/x  = (\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})/(a-b).$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac1x &= \frac1{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}}\\
&= \left(\frac1{\sqrt3 + \sqrt2} \right) \left( \frac{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt3-\sqrt2}\right)\\
&= \frac{\sqrt3-\sqrt2}{3-2}
\end{align}

In general if $x = \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b} \ne 0, a \ne b$, then $\frac1x = \frac{\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}}{a-b}$

Comment: so to rationalize you're multiplying the top and bottom by the conjugate?

Comment: yes, that is right.

Answer (score 3):

$$(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n)(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)=(\sqrt {n+1})^2-(\sqrt n)^2=1$$

Answer (score 2):

If we are told that $x = \sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}$ then it follows that $\dfrac{1}{x} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}}$

$=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}}{(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})}=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}}{(\sqrt{3})^2-(\sqrt{2})^2} = \dfrac{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}}{3-2}$

$=\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}$

This same pattern can be extended to if $x=\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}$ then $\dfrac{1}{x}=\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$